# How to get app id on Facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth, authorization, app-id

I am beginner developer. My task is receiving App_id for Oauth authorization on facebook. Can you help me what should I do for this?

Comment: please visit http://rieglerova.net/how-to-get-a-facebook-app-id/   , i think this may help you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no effort has been demonstrated by the asker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to this link [here](https://developers.facebook.com) and login with the Facebook account with which you want to create a developer app for.  Then go to the apps tab on the top right and follow the links to creat a new app.  After that go to the app in panel and there you should easily find the app key and secret.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

1. you have to make sure to use a FB-sdk which you want to use.(php/javascript/..)
2. then make sure to download them and read documentation properly.
3. After that if any error occur you can consult here.